# Android app: right-to-left language username bug

Tags: bug, android-app, rtl

I noticed this right-to-left text poblem in the StackOverflow app for Android: a comment in which I used "@username" to refer to a user whose name is in a right-to-left language, was shown completely right-to-left.

[image: Android app right-to-left bug]

Comment: Btw, is it enough to post bugs here with the "bug" tag, or do I need to start some kind of bug-reporting process?