# Minor (funny) chat star bug for Hebrew text

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, chat-stars, rtl

[image]

No, it is not the number of stars, but minutes have passed since posted. Here is the actual text, meaning "Good morning":

```
בוקר טוב
```

Tested on Chrome and IE.

Comment: This applies to usernames too, in certain locations. A RTL-clear flag needs to be added.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310158/1079354

Comment: Quick CSS fix: `#starred-posts .relativetime { unicode-bidi: embed }`

Comment: Oh. I never considered this a bug. Just enjoyable - also works in comments as I remember http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12652754#12652754

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is now fixed - thanks; sorry for the delays here!